# Sequence of sequence Best notation (Functional Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, notation

In functional analysis, one often deals with "sequences of sequences", what is the best notation for them?

For example in $l^2$, each element $x=(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ is a sequence. So if we talk about a sequence $(x_n)$ in $l^2$, it is a "sequence of sequences".

I have seen people writing superscripts, e.g. $x_n=(x_n^{(1)},x_n^{(2)},\dots)$, double subscripts $x_n=(x_{n_1},x_{n_2},\dots)$.

Are there any other ways of writing? And which is the "best" notation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the superscript notation is relatively common, but not everyone uses this. One should always be careful to ensure which variable is changing as you move down the sequence. (It can be very confusing when there are multiple indexing variables.)

Another alternative is to realise your sequence as a function $s:\mathbb N\to X$ and use the common notation for a sequence of functions. I think this is the least ambiguous way to denote such a sequence. But it is also hides some of the detail of what is happening (at least on first viewing).

I would generally avoid using indices $x_{n_i}$ since this can easily be confused with subsequence notation.

Comment: Thanks. Is this alternative superscript notation common? $x^{(n)}=(x_1^{(n)}, x_2^{(n)}, \dots, x_k^{(n)})$

Comment: To  yoyostein : That alternative superscript notation is rare , perhaps extinct.

Comment: I still use this notation, it is what I meant by superscript notarion. One should certainly not use a plain superscript $x^j$ for fear of confusing with powers. It is, or course, dependent on context which should be used.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is paired-subscripts: $(x_{n,1}\;,x_{n,2}\;,\;...).$  This avoids confusion with "subsequence notation". Since a sequence can be defined as a function with domain $\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb N\cup \{0\},$ we can also write $x_n=(x_n(1),x_n(2),..)\in l^2 .$ Different authors have their preferences. I doubt that there is any "best" way.